# How to get the call log (contact name, number, date, type , duration ) in android studio

Tags: android, android-contacts, calllog

I wrote a small program to get the call log from a device. So far It works fine. But now I want to get the contact name as well. Currently, It only shows contact number, call type (incoming, outgoing or missed call), duration, date. I tried to get the contact name as well but I couldn't. Please help with this

Thank you,
Yohan

```
/*This is the method which returns a String value and set it to the textView in xml layout file. Further, this method located in Main Activity*/

public String getCallDetails(){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);

        int number = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

        sb.append("Call Details : \n\n");
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            String phNumber = cursor.getString(number);
            String callType = cursor.getString(type);
            String callDate = cursor.getString(date);
            Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm");
            String dateString = formatter.format(callDayTime);
            String callDuration = cursor.getString(duration);
            String dir = null;
            int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
            switch (dircode){
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    dir = "Outgoing";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    dir = "Incoming";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    dir = "Missed";
                    break;
            }
            sb.append("\nPhone Number : " + phNumber+"\nCall Type : " + dir+"\nCall Date : "+dateString+"\nCall Duration : "+callDuration);
            sb.append("...................");
        }
        cursor.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }

/*This is the xml file*/

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LogFragment">

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_call"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a lookup query on the phone number to check if it belongs to a contact, and then extract the display-name of that contact.

You can also use the CACHED_NAME field of the CallLog.Calls to save you the trouble of running that lookup query, but it doesn't guaranteed to be populated, usually apps that have already ran that lookup, such as your app store the found name in the CACHED_NAME field to make the next run of the app faster.

Code:

```
public String getCallDetails(){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
    ...
    int cachedNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);

    sb.append("Call Details : \n\n");
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        ...
        String cachedName = cursor.getString(cachedNameIndex);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(cachedName)) {
            String updatedName = queryPhone(number);
            sb.append("number=" + number + ", updated-name=" + updatedName);
            // it's common practice to update CACHED_NAME field with the found name at this point
        } else {
            sb.append("number=" + number + ", cached-name=" + cachedName);
        }
        sb.append("...................");
    }
    cursor.close();
    return sb.toString();
}

private String queryPhone(String number) {
    String name = null;
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        name = cursor.getString(0);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return name;
}
```